# Scalar Product with positive definite matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, positive-definite, symmetric-matrices

Suppose $S$ is a positive definite, real and symmetric  $n\times n$ matrix and let $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$. Consider the quantity

$$
\langle(Sx)_i,(Sx)_j\rangle
$$
Is it true that this quantity is positive for every $x\neq0$? How to prove it?

Thank you.

Comment: $x$ is a vector. $S$ is a matrix. Therefore $Sx$ is another vector, and $(Sx)_i$ and $(Sx)_j$ would presumably be the $i$-th and $j$-th coordinates of that vector, which are real numbers. The inner product is an operation defined on vectors, not real numbers. So what do you mean by "$\langle(Sx)_i,(Sx)_j\rangle$"?

Comment: As you have correctly point out I made a mistake. What I mean was the matrix M_ij whose entries are (Sx)_i,(Sx)_j. My fault. Thanks for having point out the problem.